# Can I hold MySQL connection opened forever in nginx + spawn-fcgi?

Tags: c++, mysql, nginx

I use nginx + fcgi so we can c++ application which running by spawn-cgi. It's like a daemon. In that c++ application we have the main loop:

```
while ( FCGX_Accept_r( &request ) == 0 ) {

    //....FCGX_Accept_r listens for all client requests so we process them here and return HTML output to web browser....

    // Every such request I need to get some data from MySQL db. 
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL *conn = mysql_init( NULL );

    if ( !mysql_real_connect( conn, server.c_str(), user.c_str(), password.c_str(), database.c_str(), 0, NULL, 0 ) ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error( conn ) );
        //exit( 1 );
    }

    if ( mysql_query( conn, "show tables" ) ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error( conn ) );
        //exit( 1 );
    }

    res = mysql_use_result( conn );
    while ( ( row = mysql_fetch_row( res ) ) != NULL ) {
        std::cout << row[ 0 ] << "<br>\n";
    }

    mysql_free_result( res );
    mysql_close( conn );

}
```

Do I need to initiate and close connection every request or it will be better to open connection before while-loop and close connection after while-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holding a connection open over requests is actually a rather good idea, as it will save the overhead of establishing a new connection each time! However, you'd want to make sure that:

- If the connection is dropped (either during a request or between requests), you'll need to reopen it.
- If your code performs operations that alter the state of the connection, such as starting a transaction, you'll need to make sure that is properly reset between requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How can I be sure the connection has not already dropped between transactions? Is the condition before a transaction: "if ( conn == NULL ) { reconnectToMySQL(); }" will be enough for solving that problem?

Comment: No, it won't. You will need to look at the results of MySQL operations to determine if the connection has dropped.

Comment: We can use auto reconnect option here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/auto-reconnect.html